# What buttons are used in the Stream Deck

Tags: identification, components

Can anyone help or point me in the directions of what butons are used in the [Elgato Stream Deck](https://www.elgato.com/en/gaming/stream-deck)?
The buttons seem to have an intergrated LCD screen, which can be altered by the user.
[image]

Searching for 'LCD buttons/key' or 'TFT buttons/key' didn't yield any results except for [these ones](https://www.e3-keys.com/products.html#keys):
[image]

However, these are a much lower resolution then the Stream Deck buttons seem to be.
Looking for the buttons, or if they are proprietary, the closest matching ones.

Edit:
The only option I could think of would be to have a button where you can insert a tiny LCD and wire that up.

Comment: Are the stream deck buttons mechanical or are they just touch buttons? If the ladder I would not be surprised if it's just six small capacitive touch screens.

Comment: Are you sure they are separate buttons with screens? I'd do this with just one screen and a thin framework over it, holding clear plastic buttons pressing mechanical switches hidden in the border between buttons. Much simpler.

Comment: @Brian Drummond that's actually a really great option!

Comment: Seeing this video (starting when he pushes a button) it seems mechanical https://youtu.be/POt4-8b0iPE?t=239

Comment: I agree - if you look at the two frame of depressing the button the button is visibly hinged but the screen appears to be in the same place.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nkk+smartswitch&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having one screen per key increases both hardware and software complexity! The Stream Deck is actually just one big LCD screen, with a (layered?) flex on top (hollowed where the buttons are). When the plastic button is depressed, it makes contact with the flex, which ends up firing the corresponding key event.

Comment: @user8908459 the question is asking about the Stream Deck buttons. If the question is about switches with displays embedded in them, the question should be edited. The Stream Deck does not have one display per switch.